# How restore my magento store with backups

Tags: magento, shared-hosting

I have a magento website in a shared-hosting that I didn't develop -- I just use it. The problem is, whoever developed the website put the magento root in a subfolder from my domain `public_html/store` so for me to access it, I need to write `www.mydomain.com.br/store` and my website was working. The problem is that I moved my magento root to `public_html` by following these steps.  ([link](https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024838/Move+Magento+to+another+directory))  But it didn't work. So I started a restore backup for replacing my DB for my website, but now my adminpanel doesn't work. When I try to log in, it shows the message:

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlockName() on boolean in
>   /home/f5f7ohcras32/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/Block/Captcha.php
>   on line 43".

Can help me?

I tried these things:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'
WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'https://www.yourdomain.com/'
WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Rename the folder Captcha for Captcha_old,

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/seo/use_rewrites' and make it 0
```

Delete var/cache and var/session

Checked the permissions /var and files like index.php, .htacess

Comment: Are you using Captcha anywhere in the site? If not temporarily you can disable captcha